# Trying to import object in Webpack for testing, I'm lost

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js, chai

I'm working on a project for class and I'm lost regarding webpack and chai/mocha testing.

- I have a an object containing arrays called `gameData` that lives in a file called `data.js`.
- I am exporting the `gameData` variable with `export default gameData`.
- I am importing it into my `Game.js` file which has a class called Game.

What approach can I use to give my Game class access to the gameData object from my `data.js` file and how can I test that my class has access to the gameData?

Apologies if this is a silly question, but dealing with webpack and unit testing is very new to me at this time.

```js
import './data.js';

class Game {
  constructor(){
    this.currentTurn = 'p1';
    this.game = gameData;
  }
  startGame(){
    //import the data structures
    //copy the data structures
    //select 1 survey at random and remove it from the source array
    //append the question to the DOM
    //create a array with the three associated answers and remove them from source array
  }
  restartGame(){
    //clear all fields
    //revert back to starting arrays
  }
  whoseTurn(){
    if (this.currentTurn === 'p2'){
      //inputs and fields should reflect that it's players X's turn
      //player Y disabled
    } else {
      //inputs and fields should reflect that it's players Y's turn
      //player X disabled
    }
  }
}




export default Game;
```

```js
import chai from 'chai';
import Game from '../src/Game.js';
import '../src/data.js';
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Game', function() {
    it('Should have access to the data structures', function() {
        let game = new Game();
    })
}
```

error for the test:

```
1) Game
       Should have access to the data structures:
      ReferenceError: gameData is not defined
      at new Game (dist/webpack:/src/Game.js:6:1)
      at Context.<anonymous> (dist/webpack:/test/Game-test.js:8:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import gameData from './data.js'
```

or you can export gameData into global in data.js.
If you you are in browser, set `window.gameData=gameData`
or if you are in node.js, set `global.gameData=gameData`